# Does Factory Reset affect the Glass update speed?

Tags: google-glass

This morning I was modifying my timeline using the Playground and also with my own Glassware and the updates were showing in under a couple seconds.
I did a factory reset to get rid of a bunch of images and nonsense on my timeline.
Updates now take minutes to populate to the Glass.

How might factory resetting the device affect the update intervals?  Is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In general a factory reset should not impact the sync behavior of your device.

Sync may be slow for a short time while it catches up and synchronizes your existing timeline, but once that's complete, it should work great.

Since this sounds like a bug with a core Glass feature, your best bet is to reach out to the Guide team via the support link on MyGlass.  Alternatively, if you're curious, and you'd like to investigate yourself, [`adb logcat`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) might reveal more about what's going on.